# Overloading str in Python

Tags: python

I have code that looks like the following:

```
class C(str):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        print('init was called!')
        super().__init__(b)

        self.a = a


c = C(12, 'c')
```

When I try to run it, it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\math4tots\eclipseMeta\hemi\SalgebraPL\sapl.py", line 15, in <module>
    c = C(12, 'c')
TypeError: coercing to str: need bytes, bytearray or buffer-like object, int found
```

I am pretty confused. It doesn't even seem as though my init method was called. What's going on?

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but I'm using Python 3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're getting the specific error you're getting, but in any case you will need to override `__new__` as well as `__init__`.