# Constructor for class derived from str, with different signature

Tags: python, string, python-2.x

I'm trying to make a simple derived class based on `str`, with the addition of an instance variable, `flag`. For reasons I do not understand, I get an error if I try to pass the flag to the constructor:

```
>>> class Strvalue(str):
        def __init__(self, content, flag=None):
                str.__init__(self, content)
                self.flag = flag

>>> Strvalue("No problem")
'No problem'

>>> Strvalue("Problem", flag=None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#113>", line 1, in <module>
    Strvalue("Problem", flag=None)
TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

I've checked that in the succesful calls, the `Strvalue` constructor really does get called-- I haven't mistyped `__init__` or something of that sort. So what is going on?

**Edit:** According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231894/overloading-str-in-python) (and @Martijn's answer), the problem is avoided by overriding `__new__` as well. The question was *why* this was happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `__new__` instead of `__init__` when subclassing `str`, see [basic customization](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization).

```
>>> class Strvalue(str):
...     def __new__(cls, content, flag=None):
...         inst = str.__new__(cls, content)
...         inst.flag = flag
...         return inst
... 
>>> Strvalue('foo', True)
'foo'
>>> foo = Strvalue('foo', True)
>>> foo
'foo'
>>> foo.flag
True
```

Your code doesn't override `str.__new__`, so the original `str.__new__` constructor is called with your two arguments, and it only accepts one.

`str` objects are immutable, they construct a new instance in `__new__`, which then cannot be changed anymore; by the time `__init__` is called, `self` is an immutable object, so `__init__` for `str` doesn't make sense. You can still *also* define an `__init__` method, but since you already have `__new__`, there is really no need to divide the work up across two methods.

Comment: Thanks! So that's what a generic `__new__` looks like. But any idea *what* is going wrong? (I read the Basic Customization carefully before posting, and it gives no hint that this should be necessary)

Comment: @alexis: added a clarification; `str` (and `tuple` and `int` and so forth) are immutable objects; `__init__` makes no sense for those since the instance is supposed to be unalterable.

Comment: But setting the flag doesn't violate immutability-- I can set it manually after initialization, with my current version. Is `__new__` being called with the constructor's arguments?

Comment: Sure, your subclass is mutable; but the `str` class itself isn't, thus it doesn't have a meaningful `__init__` for you to reuse. Yes, as you can see from my example the constructor arguments are passed in to `__new__`.

Comment: @alexis: What is going wrong is that when you call `Strvalue('foo', True)` it calls `str.__new__` with two arguments, but it only accepts one.  `__new__` *is* the constructor; `__init__` is just the initializer.

Comment: Yes, it must be `__new__`'s signature that I'm violating! I just concluded that from Martijn's last comment... thanks!

Comment: @Martijn immutability really is not the problem: The problem is that `str.__new__` has a rigid signature. I've demoted the immutability paragraph since you don't want it deleted.

Comment: @alexis: The fact that `str` is immutable is the *reason* why you need to call `__new__`. Of course `str.__new__ ` is 'rigid'; most types do *not* define a `__new__` method, it's not that those are somehow more flexible.

Comment: No offense but I don't think that's quite right. Classes that don't define `__new__` inherit `object.__new__`, which _is_ more flexible: It accepts any argument signature. Conversely, some mutable classes provide their own `__new__`. The crucial issue is the signature.

Comment: Anyway I understand it's a question of perspective, since there's no doubt about the facts of `str`. Thank you for helping me see what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `__new__` instead of (or as well as) `__init__`.